# Calculo de precio por gramo en Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

tengo creada una tienda en Woocommerce de quesos. Agregué algunos productos con precios variables dependiendo la cantidad de gramos 100 grs, 200grs y 1 kilo, pero ahora quisiera que el cliente pudiese elegir comprar valores especificos, por ejemplo: 150 grs, 320 grs, etc y que aparezca el precio de esa cantidad. Busqué pero no encontré nada tan especifico, existe algun plugin o otra opción en woocommerce mismo para realizarlo?

http://pepilucasavegana.cl

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con este plugin: WPC Product Quantity for WooCommerce (Premium)